# Al introducir un número > 1000 (el programa me dice que lo introduzca nuevamente) y luego uno < 1000, al final imprime el número > 1000

Tags: java

Quiero un programa que por medio de un ciclo do-while reciba números menores a 1000. El problema aquí es que cuando introduzco un número mayor a 1000 (el programa me dice que lo introduzca nuevamente) y después uno inferior a 1000 al final me imprime el número mayor a 1000.

Este es el código:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a number not longer than 1000");
   boolean cheker = false;
   int a = sc.nextInt();
   do{
     if(a < 1000){
       System.out.println("your number is  not over than 1000, is valid");
       cheker = true;
     } else {
       System.out.println("your number is over than 1000, Introduce it again");
       cheker = true;
       sc.next();
     }   
  } while(!cheker);

  System.out.println("This is your number: " + a);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí va el código con algunos cambios. Un saludo.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a number not longer than 1000");
      int a;
      boolean cheker = false;       
        do{
        a = sc.nextInt();
        if(a < 1000){
           System.out.println("your number is  not over than 1000, is valid");
           cheker = true;
           }else{
              System.out.println("your number is over than 1000, Introduce it again");
              cheker = false;       
           }   
        }while(!cheker);         
       System.out.println("Tu número: " + a);
}
```

Comment: Qué cambios? Por qué esos cambios? Qué hacen? Cómo lo hacen? Por qué son necesarios? Si puso la pregunta es porque no lo entiende, si no se lo explicas no habrá aprendido nada. Si quieres responder, hazlo de manera correcta acorde a las reglas de la comunidad por favor. Estamos aquí para aprender, no para copiar y pegar. + info en [answer] y [help].

Comment: [es.so] _no es un repositorio de código_. Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo este código responde a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es aquí

```
   System.out.println("your number is over than 1000, Introduce it again");
   cheker = true;
   sc.next();
```

Hay dos problemas

1. Con "sc.next()", No asignas el resultado a "a".  Entonces println() todavía tiene el número original. (Pero debes usar "sc.nextInt()")
2. Con "cheker=true", Pienso que quieras el bucle a continuar.  Entonces debes establecer "cheker" en false.

Finalmente, la imagen en tu pregunta no es del código en tu pregunta. En la imagen, dice "Enter a number again", pero el código dice "Introduce it again".  Es importante responder a tu pregunta que que muestres el código y la salida que coincide.

---

Y la idioma inglés en tu código no es totalmente correcto.

"Enter a number not longer than 1000"  => "Enter a number not **greater/larger** than 1000"

"your number is  not over than 1000, is valid" => "Your number is  not over 1000, so it is valid".  "so" casi es "entonces". O tao vez uses "and is valid"

"your number is over than 1000, Introduce it again"  => "Your number is over 1000, enter it again".  No es correcto usar una letra mayúscula después de una coma en esto caso. (Pero es correcto después de un punto).  Y "enter" coincide con "Enter" en el primer parte de tu código.